# Is 'that' required? Does it make a difference?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

- I want **that** he become a doctor.
- I want he become a doctor.

  Is there any difference between these?

Comment: They're both awkward (and ungrammatical in my book), with the latter moreso than the former.

Comment: Almost related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154887/is-a-to-infinitive-verb-used-as-a-subjunctive

Comment: The normal phrasing would be _I want him to become a doctor._

Comment: And a starchy alternative _I desire that he become a doctor._

Answer (score 3):

*I want **that** he become a doctor.*  --> No problems.

*I want he become a doctor.*  --> Ungrammatical; alternative could be:

> I want **him to** become a doctor.

Usage:
Raymond Martin, *Self-Concern*, 1998, p.[39](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=-FX4_QZgQgwC&pg=PA39&dq=%22want%20that%20he%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RQUgU5CmMIS_rgfPtYHIBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22want%20that%20he%20%22&f=false)

> A person may **want that he be the one** to finish it so that he personally is responsible for its being finished and/or so that he gets credit appropriately for its being finished.

*ibid*., p.[70](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=-FX4_QZgQgwC&pg=PA70&dq=%22want%20that%20he%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RQUgU5CmMIS_rgfPtYHIBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22want%20that%20he%20%22&f=false)

> … he can show that C1 could not **want that he individually survive** or that both fission descendents survive, but at most that at least one of the fission descendants survive …

---

[EDIT]
There seems to be some objection to an ECM verb like *want* used in this structure, while the other verbs like *insist* present no problems.

> *I **insist that** he become a doctor.
>
>   I insist that you try some of this cake.
>
>   I insist that he come to our party.*

Comment: +1 but I am not entirely convinced that "I want that he become a doctor" is grammatically correct... it sounds funny to me but I can't quite place my finger on it.

Comment: @MrHen Maybe that it's because *want* is an ECM verb.