# why did this author use the plural verb "do" after "he"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conjugation

> Teddy's father is a prominent physician who puts a great deal of
>   pressure on the boy to achieve at a very high level. As an only child,
>   Teddy felt that all his father wanted from him was that **he do well** in
>   school. He thought that the only time there was affection in their
>   relationship was when he got a great report card. He stated unhappily,
>   "He never has any time for me ─ except to check if and how I did my
>   homework. I just want him to love me." I advised the father as
>   follows: "Give him the quality time he needs from you.

"Teddy felt that all his father wanted from him was that he **[do] well** in school."

"He" is a singular noun and therefore requires a singular verb "does", so why did this author use the plural verb **"do"** after **"he"**?

Comment: I'm no english native speaker and I hope someone can explain it better to you. In your own text you've got a similar example "I just want him to love me". Your sentence can be rephrased "His father wanted him to do well in school" It express a desire. It's not something that he actually does. It's an infinitive form and not a present form. Surely there is a better academical accurate explanation. :-) Cheers.

Comment: See [Is 'that' required? Does it make a difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154975) for a similar example

Answer (score 3):

The author is correct. He/she used "do" after "he" because he/she is using something called the subjunctive. The subjunctive is a verb form that you most commonly use when you express a wish/desire or an hypothetical situation. In this case, it expresses Teddy's father's wish for him to do well in school.

It is also used in that-clauses with certain verbs such as demand, insist, pray, recommend, suggest, etc.

Don't worry, the subjunctive is difficult for even native speakers to wrap their heads around. Here are a few more examples:

> If I **were** you, I would ask for permission.
>
> I only wish **that** what you say **were** true.
>
> They suggested **that** he **wait** till morning to travel.
>
> I demanded **that** he **speak** to me immediately.

Comment: I am a native speaker of British English and while I knew instinctively that the sentence was correct, I could not have told you why! Thanks @Phil14

Comment: @JosephRogers No problem!